# How to add multi header for specific columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header

I want my table to look like this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r0Vq.png)
and currently its looking like this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyKAW.png)

Comment: Provide your tables in text, a dictionary representation of a sample of your data (see `df.to_dict()`), a clearer description of your algorithm, and the code of your attempt. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

This website might be able to help you, in the section called Pandas Set First Two Rows As Header: [https://www.stackvidhya.com/replace-header-with-first-row-in-pandas/#:~:text=Pandas%20dataframe%20supports%20having%20multiple%20headers%20for%20each,the%20pandas%20dataframe%20will%20have%20multiple%20header%20rows.](https://www.stackvidhya.com/replace-header-with-first-row-in-pandas/#:%7E:text=Pandas%20dataframe%20supports%20having%20multiple%20headers%20for%20each,the%20pandas%20dataframe%20will%20have%20multiple%20header%20rows.) Im not sure if you can merge a header (like Modified Days) but that link should help get you closer to what you want.